# javascript error message TypeError: undefined is not a function while using ngTagsInput

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tagging, ng-tags-input

I am using [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) for tagging feature. The ngTagsInput is working fine as expected. But while loading my application. I am seeing two error messages in my Browser console.

I have attached the error message snapshot. I have tried using both regular and minified version of ngTagsInput, but no luck.

Any Idea will be appreciable.

[image: error message]

Comment: You should have a look at line 63, I guess. Set a breakpoint in your browser debugger and step through the function calls until you reach the error.

Comment: @allencoded It was due to AngularJs version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah, it was because of the AngularJs version.
https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput
Since I was using older version. Had to use another tagging plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I haven't seen this question before. :(

From [v1.0](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v100-2013-12-07) on ngTagsInput only supports Angular 1.2.1+. If you are stuck with a previous version of Angular, you can try [an older release](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/releases/tag/v0.1.5), but you'll probably miss most features.